# FreeRTOS: How could xSemaphoreTakeFromISR wake any Task

Tags: semaphore, freertos

New to FreeRTOS and trying to understand it in detail.

According to the manual here...:
https://www.freertos.org/xSemaphoreTakeFromISR.html

... it is possible that calling **xSemaphoreTakeFromISR** can cause waking up some Task from blocked state.

How is this possible ?

How could some task get to the blocked state by calling **xSemaphoreGive** in the first place ?

I understand, that semaphores and mutex are implemented by Queues and **xQueueSend** has a parameter xTicksToWait (which set to value portMAX_DELAY can cause this function to get to blocked state).
But all inner implementations of **xSemaphoreGive** set this parameter (xTicksToWait) to zero.

Please explain, why should I check the parameter **pxHigherPriorityTaskWoken** in **xSemaphoreTakeFromISR**, and in which rare occasion it can be set to pdTRUE ?

Comment: I think the API might be as is due to consistency reasons (regarding the FromISR functions). I also think you're right that signalling a semaphore can't block a task hence consuming it can't unblock one. There is a better chance getting an answer here https://forums.freertos.org